# Large npm package with mostly typescript types takes long time to load

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a private npm package full of typescript types and [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) schemas used to validate service bus messages.

I noticed that the startup time of one of the projects (gql server using nestjs/node) using the package is really slow, after investigation using [require-times](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-times) I can see that it takes 6 seconds to load the package on my local machine.

In the package all types and schemas are exported in the main file using:

```
export * from './folder/some-local-path´
```

It seems like this is causing ALL the types and schemas (and files) from the package to being required when Im starting the application even though I'm just using a small portion of the types in the package.

The package dist consist of many small files which I guess is the reason why it takes a long time to load.

How can the npm package be compiled so that not ALL files/types are loaded when I just want to load some parts of it?